# Datapipeline from Sagemaker to Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, pipeline, amazon-sagemaker

I wanted to check with the community here if they have explore the pipeline option from Sagemaker to Redshift directly.
I want to load the predicted data from Sagemaker to a table in Redshift. I was planning to do it via S3, but was wondering if there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea to stage data in S3, if acceptable in your specific use-case, is a good baseline design:

- SageMaker smoothly connects to S3 (via Batch Transform or Processing job)
- Redshift COPY statements are best practice for efficient loading of data, and can be done from S3 (*"COPY loads large amounts of data much more efficiently than using INSERT statements, and stores the data more effectively as well."* - [Redshift documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-use-copy.html))

Comment: Yes, Thats what I had in mind too. But thought there might be a better design for this.